# How to apply combn function to grouped data and generate lists or dataframes in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a grouped dataframe, lets say the 'presidential' dataset
For each group, I want to generate all possible 2-word combinations from the "name" column and save as separate lists.
I want to then bind all lists into a single vector.

Here is my initial attempt. However, the combn function does not recognize the name column...

```
presidential %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  combn(as.factor(name), 2)
```

The following error message is given:

```
Error in is.factor(x) : object 'name' not found
```

I also tried the following code with the same error message.

```
presidential %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  group_map(~combn(as.factor(name), 2))
```

The presidential dataset:

```
structure(list(name = c("Eisenhower", "Kennedy", "Johnson", "Nixon", 
                        "Ford", "Carter", "Reagan", "Bush", 
"Clinton", "Bush", "Obama"
), start = structure(c(-6190L, -3268L, -2232L, -346L, 1681L, 
                       2576L, 4037L, 6959L, 8420L, 11342L, 14264L), 
class = "Date"), 
end = structure(c(-3268L, -2232L, -346L, 1681L, 2576L, 4037L, 
                  6959L, 8420L, 11342L, 14264L, 17186L), class = 
"Date"), party = c("Republican", 

"Democratic", "Democratic", "Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", 

"Republican", "Republican", "Democratic", "Republican", "Democratic"
                  )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, 

-11L))
```

Comment: Is the column called `names` or `name`?

Comment: the column is called name

Comment: Have you tried `group_map(combn, x = as.factor(name),m=2,simplify=TRUE)`?

Comment: Could you give `dput(head(presidential))` please?

Comment: added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to specify a dummy dataframe argument which will be used for each group, `.x`. To avoid repeated combinations, you can apply `unique()` to each group, although note that you will lose self-pairs  (ie you won't get Nixon paired with Nixon, but you will get Nixon paired with Dubbya). Whether that is necessary depends on your actual input data...

```
presidential %>%
  group_by(party) %>%
  group_map(~combn(unique(.x$name),2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `combn` function does not have access to the `name` column.

Try this:

```
presidential %>% 
  group_by(party) %>%
  group_map( ~ combn(.x$name, 2)) %>%
  set_names( c('A', 'B') ) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Here, the data frame piped into `group_map` can be accessed as `.x` which allows you to access the `name` column as `.x$name`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you exactly want. The codes below are with `base R`:

- output a list

```
res <- apply(combn(seq(nrow(df)),2), 2,function(k) df[k,])
```

such that

```
> head(res)
[[1]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
2    Kennedy 1961-01-20 1963-11-22 Democratic

[[2]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
3    Johnson 1963-11-22 1969-01-20 Democratic

[[3]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
4      Nixon 1969-01-20 1974-08-09 Republican

[[4]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
5       Ford 1974-08-09 1977-01-20 Republican

[[5]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
6     Carter 1977-01-20 1981-01-20 Democratic

[[6]]
        name      start        end      party
1 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
7     Reagan 1981-01-20 1989-01-20 Republican
```

- output a data frame

```
res <- Reduce(rbind,apply(combn(seq(nrow(df)),2), 2,function(k) df[k,]))
```

such that

```
> head(res,10)
         name      start        end      party
1  Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
2     Kennedy 1961-01-20 1963-11-22 Democratic
11 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
3     Johnson 1963-11-22 1969-01-20 Democratic
12 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
4       Nixon 1969-01-20 1974-08-09 Republican
13 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
5        Ford 1974-08-09 1977-01-20 Republican
14 Eisenhower 1953-01-20 1961-01-20 Republican
6      Carter 1977-01-20 1981-01-20 Democratic
```